# Make changes to the code of more than one gameObject in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `ShopManager` class that controls upgrades the player can buy.

```
public class ShopManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ShopItem[] items;

    public PlayerController playerCon;
    public HurtEnemy hurtEnm;
    public HurtPlayer hurtPla;
    public CoinManager coinMan;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        playerCon = FindObjectOfType<PlayerController>();
        hurtEnm = FindObjectOfType<HurtEnemy>();
        hurtPla = FindObjectOfType<HurtPlayer>();
    }

    public void ApplyChangesToPlayer(ShopItem item)
    {
        switch (item.name)
        {
            case "Speed":
                playerCon.speed += 1f;
                break;
            case "Strength": 
                hurtEnm.damage++;
                break;
            case "Reduced damage":
                hurtPla.damagePerHit--;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

When opening `ShopManager` gameObject on Unity I have a problem. I have more then one enemy, and each one has `HurtPlayer` script on it, and so I need to choose if `hurtPla` will be the script on emeny1 or enemy2 since there is only one spot for it. I want the changes that I am making in this code to affect every gameObject that has the `HurtPlayer` script on it. How can I do that?

Comment: Could you please reduce the tag spamming? The only relevant tags here are `c#` and `unity-game-engine`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you should use FindObject**s**OfType instead of FindObjectOfType, then you will collect all objects of the right type in the level.

Then, loop through them.

Your code after the changes may look like this:

```
public class ShopManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ShopItem[] items;

    public PlayerController playerCon;
    public HurtEnemy hurtEnm;
    public HurtPlayer[] hurtPlayers; // now array of objects there
    public CoinManager coinMan;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        playerCon = FindObjectOfType<PlayerController>();
        hurtEnm = FindObjectOfType<HurtEnemy>();
        hurtPlayers = FindObjectsOfType<HurtPlayer>(); // now searching for all objects of type
    }

    public void ApplyChangesToPlayer(ShopItem item)
    {
        switch (item.name)
        {
            case "Speed":
                playerCon.speed += 1f;
                break;
            case "Strength": 
                hurtEnm.damage++;
                break;
            case "Reduced damage":
                foreach (var hurtPla in hurtPlayers) // now looping through all objects of type
                    hurtPla.damagePerHit--;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that amount of objects with this script can change during the game, so you need to track these changes somehow.

Also note, that FindObjectOfType requires a lot of compute resources, this operation is very slow and can kill your game performance.